# Handlebars Templates in Unit Tests, How To

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, handlebars.js, yui3

I'm creating client-side tests in YUI3, and need to compile the handlebars template for the page I'm testing.

We're running a Node app with hbs set as the rendering engine, so when requests come into the server the router responds by calling res.render() and making a call directly to the .hbs file in the views directory.

In the tests I need to instantiate handlebars template, then assign it to the DOM, but as the tests are javascript I don't have access to file stream functionality and handlebars.compile() doesn't take a path as an argument.

Basically I want to do something like this, but where the Handlebars.compile() method successively compiles the referenced template file:

```
var body = A.one(document.body);
var container = A.Node.create('<div id="test-container"></div>');
var domTemplate = Handlebars.compile('../../../../views/campaign/set-campaign-properties.hbs');
var dom = A.Node.create(domTemplate);
container.append(dom);
body.append(container);
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that there is a big differance between the client and the server, you are asking to test client side items on the server which can cause some strange issues, but there are some good tools to help. Generally when I unit test my template rendering I will use something like phantomjs or selenium. You could however use jsdom or jest to handle parsing the dom on the server side.

I have worked up a sample with jsdom, http://runnable.com/me/VIZN1VmFRzsBJu8r

```
var Handlebars = require("handlebars")
var source = "<p>Hello, my name is {{name}}. I am from {{hometown}}. I have " +
             "{{kids.length}} kids:</p>" +
             "<ul>{{#kids}}<li>{{name}} is {{age}}</li>{{/kids}}</ul>";
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data = { "name": "Alan", "hometown": "Somewhere, TX",
             "kids": [{"name": "Jimmy", "age": "12"}, {"name": "Sally", "age": "4"}]};
var templateResult = template(data);

var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env(
  templateResult,
  ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
  function (errors, window) {
    console.log("contents of p tag:", window.$("p").text());
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response JE, but my issue is I need to compile a handlebars template from an hbs file. How would I replace the template in 'source' with a template from a file in another directory?

Comment: There is a bit off a problem here because of the server vs client. The way you load it from the server is to read the file into a string and load it similar to the way I did here. On the client side you load the file via ajax. There are a few libraries to help you out. I have been using webpack that which uses the CommonJS pattern, to handle loading the objects on both the server and the client. I will add a  more complete demo, in a little bit.

Comment: Thanks JE. Looking back at original question, I see I wasn't clear about my use-case. The handlebars templates exist within .hbs templates called by the Express engine render() method during production. My need here is in regards to writing tests for the view. To do this I need to instantiate the the view and the controller. The issue I'm having is that the controller throws errors because it has multiple hooks in the DOM, and so far I'm unable to instantiate the DOM because I'm unable to call and render the handlebar template files during my tests.  Is that more clear?

Comment: Could you setup a little sample on runnable?

Comment: Thanks again JE, but I don't believe I can set-up an example, because I don't believe I could set up the environment dependencies, most notably the main issue in this case, a local .hsb file to be called from within the test. I'm a new team member on an existing application, so the overall environment is already established and functioning. I just have this one question about how to compile a handlebars template from an .hbs file within a unit test.